# Django Redirecting to a created view (pk)

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-views

I am trying to redirect to a created post after filling up the form. I tried following [Django redirect to created post after form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63057718/django-redirect-to-created-post-after-form) but I encountered this error

```
TypeError at /inquiry/
inquiry() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'
```

```
def inquiry(request,pk):

    form = RescueeForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RescueeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect ('rescuee', form.pk)

    context = {
        'form' : form
    }

    return render(request, "inquiry_page.html", context)
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('inquiry/', views.inquiry, name='inquiry'),
    path('rescuee/<int:pk>', views.rescueeview, name='rescuee'),
]
```

Edit: added comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the snippet you posted, it looks like there's a comma missing in the call to `redirect`. Also, as pointed out by others, you're passing a `pk` argument to `inquiry` that you don't use, which is causing the error. Once you've fixed this, you pointed out that there's an attribute error for `form.pk`, which just means that `form` doesn't have an attribute called `pk`. Perhaps you meant `form.id`?

Try

```
def inquiry(request):

    form = RescueeForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RescueeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('rescuee', form.id)

    context = {
        'form' : form
    }

    return render(request, "inquiry_page.html", context)
```

Alternatively, if you require the `pk` of the model created by the form, you could try:

```
def inquiry(request):

    form = RescueeForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RescueeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            rescuee_instance = form.save()
        return redirect('rescuee', rescuee_instance.pk)

    context = {
        'form' : form
    }

    return render(request, "inquiry_page.html", context)
```

Comment: I have tried the alternative solution and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see you forgot a `,` between `rescuee` and `form.pk`:
`return redirect ('rescuee', form.pk)`

Your `inquiry` view takes in an argument `pk`.
In your `urls.py`, your path for inquiry does not take the pk argument.
Change your `urls.py` like this:

```
 urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('inquiry/<int:pk>', views.inquiry, name='inquiry'), # Inquiry view takes 'pk' argument
    path('rescuee/<int:pk>', views.rescueeview, name='rescuee'),
]
```

Comment: I have tried it and encountered with my index html problem `Reverse for 'inquiry' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['inquiry/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']`. So I tried directly going to index/inquiry but encountered this `AttributeError at /inquiry/` `'RescueeForm' object has no attribute 'pk'`

Comment: @Romeo change the `form.pk` to `form.id` just like @AlonzoCathedral said. If that works, accept his answer, but please upvote mine :).

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using pk in inquiry view, when your url don't accept any value for pk.

I think this is the solution as you didn't use the pk in views code. Try it:

```
def inquiry(request):
    form = RescueeForm()
    #other codes
```

> Note: After getting your reply, I am assuming there is a problem in
> form validation. I will suggest you to try this code :
>
> ```
> # views.py
> def inquiry(request):
>
>     form = RescueeForm()
>
>     if request.method == 'POST':
>         form = RescueeForm(request.POST)
>         if form.is_valid():
>             form.save()
>             return redirect ('rescuee', form.pk)
>         else:
>             print("validation error!")
>
>     context = {
>         'form' : form
>     }
>
>     return render(request, "inquiry_page.html", context)
> ```

Comment: Actually I've tried this one too earlier but encountered 
`AttributeError at /inquiry/`
`'RescueeForm' object has no attribute 'pk'`

Comment: @Romeo May be there is a problem with form validation. Try using "return redirect ('rescuee', form.pk)" inside "if form.is_valid():" function.